# Write content Dynamicaly in Iframe

Tags: javascript

I have single page a site having 50 sites rotate in `iframe`.

I want to paste content(like `Hello`) dynamically on each site in iframe

i tried  ---

```
    myFrame = $('#myframe').contents().find('html');
    myFrame.append('Hello, World')
```

Answer (score 2):

Cross-origin security restrictions prevent browsers obeying instructions from your site to read from or modify data on other sites.

If you have the cooperation of the other sites, you can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to send them a message. They can listen for the message and modify their own DOMs based on it.